# Grab exactly 4 digits from php string

Tags: php

I would like to extract from my string variable the 4 unique digits that goes together.... meaning, if it has `12345` I do not want it to give me `1234`... i want to grab a set of numbers that has 4 numbers together only.

My current string has this:

`echo $code`

prints

`your code is 34 4325 23453 342`

i really just want it to print

`4325`

Any kind of help I can get on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What you have tried so far? Post your attempts.

Comment: Title of this answer is misleading

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
preg_match_all('/(\d{4})/', $text, $matches);
return $matches;
```

Comment: This'll return into `4325` & `2345`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `preg_match_all` with the following `regex`

```
\b(\d{4})\b
```

The above regex checks for the numbers that have an exact length of `4`

So your code looks like as

```
preg_match_all("/\b(\d{4})\b/",$str,$m);
print_r($m);
```

Comment: Downvoters post the reason for downvoting. So I can improve my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$input = 'your code is 34 4325 23453 342';

// 1. extract all numbers
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $input, $m);

// 2. find all 4-digits numbers with 4 distinct digits
foreach ($m[0] as $number) {
    if (strlen($number) == 4) {
        if ($number[0] != $number[1] && $number[0] != $number[2] && $number[0] != $number[3] && $number[1] != $number[2] && $number[1] != $number[3] && $number[2] != $number[3]) {
            echo $number, PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$code = 'your code is 34 4325 23453 342';

echo preg_replace('/.*?(\d{4}).*/', '$1', $code); //outputs 4325
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want unique digits for each blocks of 4 digits, you would have a regex like this :

```
\b(\d)(?!\1)(\d)(?!\1|\2)(\d)(?!\1|\2|\3)(\d)\b
```

I think you should use backreferences like that and I can't find another way to do it ..

It checks if each digit (\d) differs from the previous ones